# Android ProgressBar: how to set secondary color programmatically

Tags: android, colors, progress-bar

I need to set secondary progress bar color **programmatically**.

I only see the method

```
ProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(drawable)
```

for set the primary color, but there isn't a method for set the secondary color.

How I can do it?

Comment: Michele, are u found solution ? im stuck too with this problem :(

Answer (score 5):

`ProgressBar.getProgressDrawable()` returns a `LayerDrawable` in which:

```
LayerDrawable progressDrawable = (LayerDrawable) getProgressDrawable();
Drawable backgroundColor = progressDrawable.getDrawable(0);
Drawable secondaryColor = progressDrawable.getDrawable(1);
Drawable primaryColor = progressDrawable.getDrawable(2);
```

I try to modify the colors whit (example):

```
progressDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId(progressDrawable.getId(2), new ClipDrawable(...));
```

but sometimes the screen freeze, sometimes crash.
Finally I abandoned the search for lack of time.
Sorry :(

Michele

Comment: Exactly what i needed. This is awesome!

Answer (score 3):

Probably not relevant to Michele, but perhaps it will help someone else..

```
ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) fullView.findViewById(R.id.main_progressbar);
LayerDrawable progressDrawable = (LayerDrawable)progress.getProgressDrawable();
Drawable drawable = activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.WHATEVER_YOU_WANT);
ClipDrawable cd = new ClipDrawable(drawable, Gravity.LEFT,ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
progressDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.progress, cd);
```

Answer (score 2):

The drawable you specify using `setProgressDrawable` has background, primary and secondary drawables in it. Here is an [example of `ProgressBar` drawable](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/res/res/drawable/progress_horizontal.xml&q=ProgressBar%20drawable&d=1) that is shipped with android:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient ...  />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient .../>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient ...  />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer.
But i must do it with java not with xml.

Comment: I too wanted to do in java, but creating two xml files (or more given your needs)  and selecting the one you wanted is so easy, fast and clean, I stuck with this method.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

You can use a drawable xml like this to set progressdrawable

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/progress_bar_nor">       
</item>    
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/progress_bar_nor">       
</item>
<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/progress_bar_sel"/>
```

Refer this link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27144594/1554031