# Android - Circular progress bar not working

Tags: android, xml, android-progressbar

I am trying to create an indeterminate progress bar to signify loading in my app. However after trying countless xml layouts and different bits of code, I can't seem to get anything working. This is my main fragment's xml file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context="com.example.dwinnbrown.xxx.FirstFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/prgrsbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:max="500"
        android:progress="0"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular" />


</FrameLayout>
```

And my circular.xml file:

```
<shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="7.0">

    <gradient
        android:centerColor="#007DD6"
        android:endColor="#007DD6"
        android:startColor="#007DD6"
        android:angle="0"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" ></gradient>
</shape>
```

However the output appears like this - am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll get to the progress bar, but there are another thing to improve first:

FrameLayout is meant for children that are stacked on top of each other, but it doesn't support aligning the views inside it.

So an easy start would be to use a Relativelayout as a root view and then you can align the Progressbar in the middle of the view easily.

Now, to the progressbar, I haven't done your usecase myself. But I would recommend you to strip it down to the essensitals first to see that it's dispalyed, so:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/prgrsbar"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_height="150dp"/>
```

This should show you a simple progressbar that simply keeps on spinning in a circle. If it doesn't there's a problem elsewhere.

After that you can build up with adding the min / max values to see that it becomes straight

And lastly, add the drawable, which I only guess, could be the problem here and we can look on exactly why that fails, but then we have found the root cause and can easily search on the error. :)

Edit:

I looked online a bit and from what I found the drawable should look something similar to this (untested though): [How to set color to secondary drawable in progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244994/how-to-set-color-to-secondary-drawable-in-progress-bar)

Comment: Ok thanks for the help I will test that all out now.

Comment: Ok that presents a horizontal sliding bar now - unfortunately not circular.

Comment: The progressbar should be circular if it doesn't have a max and progress values, are you sure they are not there?
Either way, it's a start, that means the view is now displayed! :)

Comment: For some reason the app is failing to build with <relativelayout> i am using fragments if this makes a difference

Comment: Mm, no that should be fine.

It's "RelativeLayout" inside the xml.
Maybe you're fetching the view inside the fragment and try to store it in a FrameLayout variable?

Without the stacktrace it's hard to know.

Comment: Don't think so...I am now also getting a broken pipe error!

Comment: Rebooted and the pipe error seems to have gone. i will try again

Comment: It suddenly worked after I cleaned my project! Thank you

Comment: No worries, happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Android already has a circular progress bar built in, try this:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:id="@+id/prgrsbar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

You can use `progressBarStyleSmall` instead of `progressBarStyleLarge` if it is too big, or customize it yourself.