# Android progress bar horizontal secondary progress color

Tags: android, progress-bar

I want a progress bar with two colors. And sometime i want to increment red color progress and some time in green color. In simple words i want to divide the progress bar in two. One green section and other red if i want to increment the progress in red it will increment in the red and same as for the green. Note that the progress start from left. How can i achieve this. I know that i should use the secondary progress but how? Here is my code and what i am trying to do.

```
final float[] roundedCorners = new float[] { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
    ShapeDrawable pgDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(
            roundedCorners, null, null));

    if (answer == true) {

        pgDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor(greenColor));
        Log.i("green", ": should work");

    } else if (answer == false) {

        pgDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor(redColor));
        Log.i("red", ": should work");
    }

    ClipDrawable progress = new ClipDrawable(pgDrawable, Gravity.LEFT,
            ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
    progressBarTotal.setProgressDrawable(progress);

    progressBarTotal.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
            android.R.drawable.progress_horizontal));

    if (TotalPercent >= 102) {

        Toast.makeText(ProcessGame.this, "Full", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        progressBarTotal.setProgress(TotalPercent);

        TotalPercent = (TotalPercent + 1);

    }
```

I dont want to mess with xml stuff if this can be done in java.

Comment: When green is selected it overwrites the red color and increments progress same as for the red.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own view.

```
public class CustomProgressBar extends View{
    public CustomProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attribs){
        super(context, attribs);
        float xRadius = 5f, yRadius =  = 5f;

        Paint emptyPaint = new Paint();
        emptyPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);


        Paint greenPaint = new Paint();
        greenPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        Paint redPaint = new Paint();
        redPaint.setColor(Color.RED);

        Rectf emptyBar = new Rectf(0,0,0,0);
        Rectf greenBar = new Rectf(0,0,0,0);
        Rectf redBar = new Rectf(0,0,0,0);
    }

    public void setProgress(float greenProgress, float redProgress){
        //progress should be between 0f and 1f
        //but you can change it, just change how the width is calculated
        emptyBar.set(0,0,getWidth(), getHeight());
        greenBar.set(0,0,getWidth() * greenProgress, getHeight());
        redBar.set(0,0,getWidth() * redProgress, getHeight());
        //force the view to draw again
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawRoundRect(emptyBar, xRadius,yRadius, emptyPaint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(greenBar, xRadius,yRadius, greenPaint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(redBar, xRadius,yRadius, redPaint);
    }
}
```

in xml the view would look something like

```
<com.mydomain.widgets.CustomProgressBar 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dip"
/>
```

The code is just an example of how to get it done. Some improvements can be made, e.g you can store the width and height values of the view in a local variable to avoid calling `getWidth` and `getHeight` all the time, but you can only do this in specific places, like inside your activities `onWindowFocusChanged` callback, otherwise getWidth and getHeight will return 0. Empty bar can also be intialized with proper values once to avoid setting everytime.

Comment: @MohsinShafqat only thing i've found is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235890/android-progressbar-how-to-set-secondary-color-programmatically), as you can see it uses xml, the code i've given you can be done entirely without use of xml.

Comment: but i used ProgressBar class not view